# Handling different URL paths while hitting a single endpoint (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman, endpoint

I am using express nodejs to hit an endpoint:

```
app.use("/number", numberRouter);
```

Now I have to handle URL in which the path is different. Here we have three different paths in the same URL:

- https://localhost:8080/number/one
- https://localhost:8080/number/two
- https://localhost:8080/number/three

The file in which the numberRouter is handled:

```
numberRouter.post("/", async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    var url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

    //what I want to do
    if (req.path == "one") {
        //do something
    } 
    else if (req.path == "two") {
       //do something
    }
});
```

What I want to achieve is that once I hit the `number` endpoint, I fetch the full URL, extract out it's `path` and based on the `path` I do further processing instead of hitting three different endpoints (`/number/one`, `/number/two`, `/number/three`).
Is this possible?

I am using postman for testing and if I send a post request with the following URL:
`localhost:8080/number/one` the post request fails. I want something like this in the code:

```
numberRouter.post("/variablePath", async (req:Request, res:Response) => { ... }
```

where the `variablePath` is set via postman (`one`, `two` or `three`) and then processed here.

### SOLUTION (following @traynor's answer):

```
app.use("/number", numberRouter);
```

```
numberRouter.post("/:pathNum", async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    if (req.path === "/one") {
        //do something
    } 
    else if (req.path === "/two") {
       //do something
    }
});
```

The post request via postman: `localhost:8080/number/:pathNum`.
In postman set the value of `pathNum` in the `Params` section under the `Path Variables` heading.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

add your parameter to the router, for example `/:myparam`, and then check it and run your code:

```
numberRouter.post("/:myparam", async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    const myParam = req.params.myparam;

    //what I want to do
    if (myParam == "one") {
        //do something
    } 
    else if (myParam == "two") {
       //do something
    }

});
```

Comment: Ain't parameters and path two different things? In the documentation link that you've shared, the `req.path` heading is right below the `req.params` heading. What I need is `req.path`.

Comment: @BoringCookie when you start the app, routes cannot be added dynamically, so dynamic paths are solved/processed with req.params, req.query, and custom middleware